# $http TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined - in a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Not sure why this is a problem

I have get error on $http

**Index.html**   // References to files

```
<script src="common/services/common.services.js"></script>
<script src="common/services/deviceService.js"></script>
```

**common.services.js**  // I'm not using ngResource /$resource for $http obviously  **do I need to use httpprovider ?**

```
(function () {
      "use strict";

angular
    .module("common.services",   // name of module
    ["ngResource"])   // array that defines the dependencies  ( ngResource contains the $resource service)
} ());
```

PROBLEM is here...

**deviceService.js**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("common.services")
    .factory("deviceService",
    ["$http",deviceService]);

    function deviceService($http) {

       function httpGetCost(cost, amount, $http) {
           $http.get('../api/deviceEvents.json')
            .then(function (result) {
           //.......
       }

       return {  outsideCall: httpGetCost }
   }

} ());
```

1. I'm not sure purpose of common.service.js  really...
2. Do I need $http to have some httpprovider service reference?
3. I gather I'm not injecting in $http correctly?

Comment: I guess you should not pass $http to your inner function httpGetcost(). Could you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did not inject your `$http` properly - just a minor syntax error.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
      .module("common.services")
      .factory("deviceService", ["$http", deviceService]);

    function deviceService($http) { //this is the real $http that gets injected

      function httpGetCost(cost, amount) { //remove your $http here
        $http.get('../api/deviceEvents.json')
          .then(function(result) {
              //.......
            }

            return {
              outsideCall: httpGetCost
            }
          }

      }());
```

Comment: Great, with this $httpBackend I just cannot WIN ,   i do get past that error but then   No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1418)